# How Do I Get A Coffee Mug/Cup Icon To My Applets?

Tags: panel-applets

I've seen someone had a coffee cup on their taskbar, in their indicators, and was wondering how I can get it. I think it was something to do with Java.

Also, how do I make my own applet, even if it's just a picture?

Answer (score 2):

the application you are looking for is called **caffeine** (http://ubuntu-tweak.com/app/caffeine/)

[image]

depending on your ubuntu version you can install it using these commands

```
sudo -s
add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install caffeine
```

there is no port to Ubuntu 12.10 though, so if you are using Ubuntu 12.10, you have to wait until the developer packed it for Quantal